# How to add a schema to a table in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0, information-schema

How can I add a $_schema array to a table in cakephp3? The schema looks like:

```
public $_schema = array(

    'id' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'length' => 11
    ),
    'uuid' => array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'length' => 40
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'length' => 255
    )

);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the schema inside the intitialize method in the table like this:

```
//src/Model/Table/ContactsTable.php
use Cake\Database\Schema\Table as SchemaTable;



public function initialize(array $config){
    $table = new SchemaTable(null);
    $table
        ->addColumn('id', [
            'type' => 'integer',
            'length' => 11,
            'null' => false
        ])
        ->addColumn('uuid', [
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 255,
            'null' => false
        ])
        ->addColumn('name', [
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 255,
            'null' => false
        ]);

    $this->schema($table);
}
```

Answer can be found under https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5251